# How to install OpenCV 3.3.1. Tracking API (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I installed OpenCV 3.3.1. from the sources from GitHub. What I want to use is the tracking API like in the following tutorial:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/d0a/tutorial_introduction_to_tracker.html

But it seems like the needed module is not included. I also tried to use the contrib library (https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib) as well, but it doesn't build for this OpenCV version. I always get errors like:

```
    error: ‘NMSBoxes’ is not a member of ‘cv::dnn’
        cv::dnn::NMSBoxes(bbox, outProbabillities, 0.3f, 0.4f, indexes);
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this as well. I had cloned both "opencv" and "opencv_contrib" from Github, and checked out "opencv" at tag 3.3.1, but failed to check out "opencv_contrib" at the same tag level.  That produced the error looking for ‘NMSBoxes’.

After checking out "opencv_contrib" at the same tag as "opencv", the build ran to completion.

Comment: Thx @Rick 0xfff, 2 days after my post the GitHub Repos seemed to be synchronized again as another pull solved the problem for me then. Thanks a lot for your anwer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Checking version of opencv and version of opencv_contrib.

   1.1 command: "cd opencv" ( source folder ) => command: "git tag" => show version.

   1.2 command: "cd opencv_contrib" ( source folder ) => command: "git tag" => show version.
2. Set version  of opencv same with version of opencv_contrib.

   2.1 command: "git checkout 3.3.1" at "opencv".

   2.1 command: "git checkout 3.3.1" at "opencv_contrib".
3. command: "cd ".
4. command: "cmake -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/modules ".
5. command: "make -j4".

Comment: This answer, although it looks like it has useful information, is not complete without a better explanation.